# Why won't this code draw parabola?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

Why won't this code draw parabola? It is as simple as it can be - for every x calculate y using given function. Given y=x^2 i should draw down facing parabola with vertex in top left corner, yet it only draws some displaced dots.

```
private void DrawParabole(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Width; x++)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(
                Pens.Black, 
                x,
                FY(x), 
                1, 
                1
             );
        }
    }

    private int FY(int x)
    {
        int y = A*x^2 + B*x + C;
        return y;
    }
```

Comment: What are the values of `A`, `B` and `C` when you call `FY(x)`?

Comment: For simpicity, lets assume A=1, B=0, C=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting the wrong values/scattered dots is because you are using the `XOR` or `^` operator instead of `Math.Pow()`.

In order to calculate, lets say, `A*x^2` you must use [Math.Pow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) and not `^`:

```
int y = A*(Math.Pow(x, 2)) + B*x + C;
return y;
```

That should solve it for you, if it doesn't then use this:

```
int y = A*(Math.Pow((double)x, 2D)) + B*x + C;
return y;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If your code is C#, ^ is the bitwise XOR. Use Math.Pow() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the corrected math by [MatthewRz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135893/56763):

```
    private int FY(int x)
    {
        int y = (int)(A * (Math.Pow(x, 2)) + B * x + C);
        return y;
    }
```

You will still only see dots though (since Y change more than X for each step), use the following loop to get lines between the dots:

```
    private void DrawParabole(Graphics g, int w)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(
                Pens.Black,
                x,
                FY(x-1),
                x,
                FY(x));
        }
    }
```